# Is rollback needed if query completed with errors?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a query like this:

```
use DataIncremental
go
DECLARE @row_terminator CHAR;
SET @row_terminator = CHAR(10); -- or char(10)

BEGIN TRAN tran2


DECLARE @stmt NVARCHAR(2000);
SET @stmt = '
  BULK INSERT accn_adjustments
   FROM ''C:\Users\agordon\Desktop\incrementaljan2012\accn_adjustments_201112302112.txt''
   WITH 
      (
        firstrow=2,
FIELDTERMINATOR = ''|''  ,
ROWS_PER_BATCH=10000
   ,ROWTERMINATOR='''+@row_terminator+'''
   )'
exec sp_executesql @stmt;
SET @stmt = '
  BULK INSERT accn_adjustments
   FROM ''C:\Users\agordon\Desktop\incrementaljan2012\accn_adjustments_201112312112.txt''
   WITH 
      (
        firstrow=2,
FIELDTERMINATOR = ''|''  ,
ROWS_PER_BATCH=10000
   ,ROWTERMINATOR='''+@row_terminator+'''
   )'
exec sp_executesql @stmt;
SET @stmt = '
  BULK INSERT accn_adjustments
   FROM ''C:\Users\agordon\Desktop\incrementaljan2012\accn_adjustments_201201022101.txt''
   WITH 
      (
        firstrow=2,
FIELDTERMINATOR = ''|''  ,
ROWS_PER_BATCH=10000
   ,ROWTERMINATOR='''+@row_terminator+'''
   )'
exec sp_executesql @stmt;
SET @stmt = '
  BULK INSERT accn_adjustments
   FROM ''C:\Users\agordon\Desktop\incrementaljan2012\accn_adjustments_201201032101.txt''
   WITH 
      (
        firstrow=2,
FIELDTERMINATOR = ''|''  ,
ROWS_PER_BATCH=10000
   ,ROWTERMINATOR='''+@row_terminator+'''
   )'
exec sp_executesql @stmt;
```

The reason I put `begin tran tran2` is to ensure that if there are errors I can just do a `rollback`

I ran the code and the message I got was `"query completed with errors"`

SSMS did NOT state that some `rows were inserted` as it usually does.

When I tried to do a `rollback tran tran2`, it said that that transaction never began

So my question is, **were rows committed to the database or not?**

If not, then why did it state "query completed with errors" shouldnt it just have said query did not complete due to errors?

Comment: Do you have the `XACT_ABORT` option switched on? Also is that your entire code? You don't have an explicit rollback or commit anywhere?

Comment: If you don't have `XACT_ABORT` on or any explicit error handling. [It depends on the error](http://www.sommarskog.se/error-handling-I.html#whathappens)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Description

Since SQL Server 2005 you can use error handling using `TRY` `CATCH`

> **TRY...CATCH (Transact-SQL)** Implements error handling for Transact-SQL that is similar to the exception handling in the Microsoft Visual C# and Microsoft Visual C++ languages. A group of Transact-SQL statements can be enclosed in a TRY block. If an error occurs in the TRY block, control is passed to another group of statements that is enclosed in a CATCH block.

#### Sample

```
BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRANSACTION

     -- do something

    COMMIT TRAN -- Transaction successfull, commit!
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
        ROLLBACK TRAN --RollBack if error occured
END CATCH
```

#### More Information

- [Microsoft TechNet - TRY...CATCH (Transact-SQL)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175976.aspx)

Comment: can we do a chat please? have some more questions

Comment: I don't have much time but we can start a chat, yes.

Comment: If we write some more comments it will come automatically ;) I don't know yet, how to start manually.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7005/discussion-between-dknaack-and-i)

Answer (score 1):

From [the documentation on BULK INSERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx):

> The BULK INSERT statement can be executed within a user-defined
>   transaction. Rolling back a user-defined transaction that uses a BULK
>   INSERT statement and BATCHSIZE clause to import data into a table or
>   view using multiple batches rolls back all batches sent to SQL Server.

sp_executesql is contained within the outermost transaction (the one you start with `BEGIN TRANSACTION`), so these bulk inserts should all be transactional as a unit.

As @MartinSmith's comment implies, XACT_ABORT may have aborted this outermost transaction if it ran too long.

Comment: `XACT_ABORT` doesn't abort based on time as you suggest. It just means the transaction is automatically rolled back if an error occurs.